# Saudi transit visa

Tags: visas, transit, saudi-arabia

I’m travelling on KL flight 0421 from Amsterdam to Muscat. This flight stops in Dammam en route for 45 mins ... I do not believe you get off the plane.

I am presuming I won’t need a Saudi transit visa for this but can somebody please confirm?

Comment: Could you please state your citizenship, as this is often relevant for visas.

Answer (score 2):

You **do not** require a Saudi transit visa for this itinerary even if you have to change planes.

> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>
> Passengers transiting through Dammam (DMM), Jeddah (JED) or Riyadh (RUH) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 12 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
> Only one transit stop-over in Saudi Arabia is permitted.

Source: [Timatic via Emirates](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=NL&NV=Netherlands&DC=OM&DV=Oman&TC=SA&TV=Saudi%20Arabia&h=49662a317f6dad2598bf9b3934837b6d7b643bd)

Comment: +1, but why would they need a visa on the way back?

Comment: The last sentence of their quote seems to suggest that, I also have no clue why would that be so. Or probably it means that one stop-over per leg of your ininerary. But that would then be a useless warning as most if not all scheduled stopovers are 1 per country.

Comment: @jpatokal I think it means in the same flight, so no domestic connection as you'd need to go through immigration then and need a visa.

Comment: @BritishSam every airside transit means that. Then why does Saudi Arabia have such a note for a single transit only?

Comment: Well what does it mean, only one ever? In a year? This is what airline staff use to see if someone is allowed on a flight, they'd see they only have one stop in SA on that flight so the customer may board?

Comment: That's the confusion we have: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/133393/what-does-timatic-mean-by-saying-only-one-transit-stop-over-in-saudi-arabia-is